# Django Admin, registering multiple models

Tags: python, django

Previously I had admin.py as follows:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 3

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ItemInline]

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

And it worked just fine but I have created 2 more models: OrderItem and Faq and I'm not sure how to register them

I've tried:

```
admin.register(Event, EventAdmin, OrderItem, Faq)(admin.ModelAdmin)
```

without luck, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it several times:

```
admin.register(Event, EventAdmin)
admin.register(OrderItem, OrderItemAdmin)
admin.register(Faq, FaqAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write admin classes for the other two models and write:

```
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
admin.site.register(OrderItem, OrderItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Faq, FaqAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy way!

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

#Register your models here.

myModels = [Category,Reader,AudioBook,AudioBookEpisode]
admin.site.register(myModels)
```